# What day in April will Ubuntu 8.04 Hardy Server be scheduled for end of life

Tags: release-management

I searched on Google to find the end of life date of Ubuntu 8.04 Server (Hardy Heron) but to only find that it is in "April 2013".

My question is, will I get updates in April or it ends on the first of April ?

Thanks !

References:

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Ubuntu_releases#Table_of_versions
- https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases#Stable

Comment: This question was useful in a specific period of time, since 8.04 server is EOL now this question can be closed.

Answer (score 1):

The date is currently 9th of May 2013. Subject to change however.